# How to remove all block device files that no longer have corresponding physical devices attached?

Tags: unmount, dmcrypt

I have a `/dev/dm-#` block device file and a link to it from `/dev/mapper/somename` even after detaching the physical device.

Is it safe to just use `rm` on both? Is there a way to rescan physical devices and remove unneeded links in `/dev/mapper`? And, possibly, reset alphabetic counter for new block devices (as in /dev/sd**c**)?

`partprobe` isn't helping, and I don't see anything related in `blockdev` manual.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo cryptsetup luksClose somename
```

In my case it was the result of using `cryptsetup luksOpen` and detaching the device without closing it.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore.